# Cargar un array dese un json me está generando doble [[]] - javascript, laravel

Tags: javascript, json

desde mi controlador estoy enviando un json para utilizarlo en mi vista, no hay ningún problema hasta aquí

```
$mailRecipients = json_encode($this->meoRepository->getMailRecipients($id));
        return view('digest-report.edit', ['digestReport' => $digestReport, 'businessTypes'=>$businessTypes, 'mailRecipients'=>$mailRecipients]);
```

luego esto lo recibo en mi vista para trabajar con él, pero aquí es donde el string termina con doble corchete `[[]]`

lo hago de esta manera

```
let recipientsArray =[];
                recipientsArray.push({!! $mailRecipients !!});
            $('#recipients').val(JSON.stringify(recipientsArray));
```

con esto en mi vista termino con lo siguiente

```
[[{"name":"pila1","email":"pila1@gmail.com"},{"name":"pila2","email":"pila2@gmail.com"},{"name":"pila3","email":"pila3@gmail.com"},{"name":"pila4","email":"pila4@gmail.com"}]]
```

lo más probable es que sea por la parte de let recipientsArray =[]; pero no sé cómo iniciar la variable, ahí estoy mal

gracias por su ayuda :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No es necesario ponerle el `array.push`, basta con solo utilizar el `JSON.stringify`, asi

```
// Recibimos el valor
let recipientsArray = '{!! $mailRecipients !!}';

// Lo convertimos en texto JSON
$('#recipients').val(JSON.stringify(recipientsArray))
```

Comment: gracias! era eso, no sé de javascript y no sabía si había que iniciar la variable o algo así

Comment: No es necesario, tambien puedes hacerlo directamente `JSON.stringify('{!! $mailRecipients !!}')`, respetando las comillas simples, ya que `$mailRecipients ` es un valor y puedes utilizar como quieras